# JavaScript weekday list get

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, weekday

I need to create a JavaScript function for the below requirements. I need to get every week day date list. If you know nodeJs package tell me that. Thank you for your attention.

```
Example - 
 2022-01-03
 2022-01-04
 2022-01-05
 2022-01-06
 2022-01-07

 2022-01-10
 2022-01-11
 2022-01-12
 2022-01-13
 2022-01-14 
 ..........
 ..........
 until year-end
```

like this pattern (only Monday to Friday)

Comment: How about using this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time

Comment: add code what you tried so far

Comment: @Najmieh Sadat Safarabadi It is ok bro. But I have a question about how to do that in this package? I think it has no function for get week day list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getWeekDaysForYear(year) {
  const isLeap = year % 4 === 0;
  const numberOfDays = isLeap ? 366 : 365;
  let currentDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));

  const weekDays = [];

  for(let i = 1; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
    currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    if (currentDate.getDay() === 0 || currentDate.getDay() === 6) {
      continue;
    }
    weekDays.push(currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
  }

  return weekDays;
}
```

```
console.log(getWeekDaysForYear(2022));
```

This is a simple function which returns all the weekdays for the specified year in an array.

Comment: Your leap year function isn't quite correct.

Comment: @Krushil Dhamelia can we get within month range?

Ex :- instead of year, can we pass startDate and endDate
startDate - 2022-01-01 , endDate- 2022-01-30

Then can we get weekdays above this condition?

Comment: Yes checkout the new answer for this date range

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's `Date` object overflows, so you can use:

```js
for (i=1;i<366;i++) {
if (i%7==1 || i%7==2) continue;
const d = new Date(2022, 0, i);
document.write(d.toDateString(),'<br>');
}
```

You will need to watch for leap years, and recalculate which days are the weekend every year.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const endDate = new Date(2022,1,2);
const date = new Date(); //today

while (endDate > date) {
  const weekDay = date.getDay();
  if (weekDay != 6 && weekDay != 0) {
    let year = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(date);
    let month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: '2-digit' }).format(date);
    let day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { day: '2-digit' }).format(date);
    console.log(`${year}-${month}-${day}`);
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we're play code golf…

```js
function getWeekDays(year) {
  // Start on 1 Jan of given year
  let d = new Date(Date.UTC(year, 0));
  let result = [];
  do {
    // Only push dates that aren't Sat (6) or Sun (0)
    d.getDay() % 6 ? result.push(d.toLocaleDateString('en-CA')) : null;
    // Increment date
    d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
  // Until get to 1 Jan again
  } while (d.getMonth() + d.getDate() > 1)
  return result;
}

console.log(getWeekDays(new Date().getFullYear()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getWeekDaysForDateRange(start, end) {
  const [startYear, startMonth, startDate] = start.split("-");
  const [endYear, endMonth, endDate] = end.split("-");
  let beginDate = new Date(Date.UTC(startYear, startMonth - 1, startDate - 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
  let closeDate = new Date(Date.UTC(endYear, endMonth - 1, endDate, 0, 0, 0, 0));

  const weekDays = [];

  while(beginDate.getTime() !== closeDate.getTime()) {
    beginDate = new Date(beginDate.getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    if (beginDate.getDay() === 0 || beginDate.getDay() === 6) {
      continue;
    }
    weekDays.push(beginDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
  }
  return weekDays;
}

console.log(getWeekDaysForDateRange('2022-01-01', '2022-01-10'));
```

Something like this would work for date range as you want!